# NoClassDefFoundError with the ?.let{} block in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide, kotlin-null-safety

I cannot figure out why I am getting the following error:

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution
>   of:
>   Lcom/somecompany/someapp/common/glide/GlideWrapper$loadCircularProfileImg$1$1;
>                                                                                    at
>   com.somecompany.someapp.common.glide.GlideWrapper.loadCircularProfileImg(GlideWrapper.kt:31)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.somecompany.someapp.main.MainActivity.showSideBarProfPhoto(MainActivity.kt:179)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.somecompany.someapp.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:115)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

with the code:

```
fun loadCircularProfileImg(ctx: Context, user: User?, targetImageView: ImageView) {

        user?.let {
            // With let getting a NoClassDefFoundError error 

            GlideApp.with(ctx)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(it.profImgUrl))
                    .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(targetImageView) {
                        override fun setResource(resource: Bitmap?) {
                            // Will add code here
                        }
                    })
        }
    }
```

but not with:

```
fun loadCircularProfileImg(ctx: Context, user: User?, targetImageView: ImageView) {

    if (user != null) {   // With this the code works

        GlideApp.with(ctx)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(user.profImgUrl))
                .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(targetImageView) {
                    override fun setResource(resource: Bitmap?) {
                        // Will add code here
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/let-vs-if-not-null/3542

Comment: i used the above code and it working perfect without any error.

Answer (score 1):

when you call loadCircularProfileImg that time user class are define i am call same method and not getting any error like below...

```
        loadCircularProfileImg(this,User(),imageview)
```

i am used above code and not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a [Kotlin bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29595) and fixed in version 1.5.0.